# Predicted values from a linear mixed model don't form a straight line even though no (higher order) transformations/polynomials have been specified

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, predictive-models, repeated-measures

To assess if `age` is related to my `continuous_outcome` in my repeated measurements data, I've specified a linear mixed model with a random intercept and slope and a continuous first-order autoregressive variance-covariance structure for the residuals. Because my `continuous_outcome` was véry skewed, I've transformed this variable (natural log transformation, `continuous_outcome_log`) and ran the model using this variable.

The data looks as follows:

```
library(nlme)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyverse)

mydata <- structure(list(pat_id = c(61, 8, 179, 13, 153, 80, 273, 142, 
                                    202, 2, 61, 127, 135, 49, 20, 25, 315, 48, 157, 171, 29, 271, 
                                    105, 14, 14, 84, 180, 125, 255, 135, 39, 49, 320, 160, 197, 189, 
                                    154, 77, 30, 75, 50, 103, 115, 80, 88, 34, 310, 81, 75, 82), 
                         age = c(57.1, 61.4, 60.9, 58.7, 65.4, 44.8, 59, 47.5, 63.4, 
                                 59.8, 55, 66.1, 50.8, 62.8, 71.1, 48.9, 58.1, 49.8, 71.1, 
                                 56.6, 50.1, 40.4, 62.3, 53.3, 53.8, 70.4, 67.2, 68.5, 57.9, 
                                 54.3, 60.9, 61, 54.1, 70.1, 52.4, 70.4, 55.7, 60.7, 56.1, 
                                 60.9, 60, 52.1, 48.8, 40.7, 58.4, 65.3, 62.7, 64.8, 61.2, 
                                 70.7), continuous_outcome = c(2605.440900389, 2063.9, 1929.46472167969, 
                                                               5341.496223986, 1119.6044921885, 566.255950927734, 1880.5290222168, 
                                                               3215.77453613281, 603.7692803513, 7594.527875667, 1775.66680908203, 
                                                               2260.04156843471, 4565.098635412, 6948.76321012, 35685.6, 
                                                               1170.96138000488, 3152.85720825195, 765.9703779527, 4638.270794249, 
                                                               7962.890625, 45.4402923583984, 76.2939453125, 1466.9, 4207.615392583, 
                                                               3410.15625, 11076.9451141357, 20190.12993463, 822.127334531, 
                                                               7512.78955078125, 4146.38368225098, 4292.35992431641, 6393.09959411621, 
                                                               465.39306640625, 8409, 737.1825748757, 3898.624597663, 8238.67454528809, 
                                                               3054.98580932617, 526.4287617193, 7612.90808598633, 2247.54676818848, 
                                                               9231.37016296387, 1067.416015625, 775.980377197266, 10118.2, 
                                                               6744.3, 7616.49208068848, 356.531524658203, 8069.160616877, 
                                                               25596.8906372702), continuous_outcome_log = c(7.86574093001633, 
                                                                                                             7.63283707807243, 7.56551604134912, 8.58344828040522, 7.0216235438582, 
                                                                                                             6.34081061444271, 7.53984003495667, 8.07613443965171, 6.40484703050537, 
                                                                                                             8.93531491566494, 7.48249430865052, 7.72358085708673, 8.42641442900534, 
                                                                                                             8.84646286749209, 10.4825305471662, 7.06643401737976, 8.05638149327426, 
                                                                                                             6.64244817996005, 8.44231247645808, 8.98267293141324, 3.83816745221036, 
                                                                                                             4.34761562539111, 7.29158808696319, 8.34488898720956, 8.13480658905054, 
                                                                                                             9.31271148408861, 9.9129986748043, 6.71311090867393, 8.92449521812674, 
                                                                                                             8.33023297640332, 8.36482490452301, 8.76313090568181, 6.14502876872992, 
                                                                                                             9.03717675296699, 6.60419118543475, 8.26863557047525, 9.01671612519243, 
                                                                                                             8.02485750673053, 6.26801380735694, 8.93773186515778, 7.71803940572248, 
                                                                                                             9.13047108358574, 6.97393247141267, 6.65541509547637, 9.22218988833333, 
                                                                                                             8.81660124504343, 8.93820247123851, 5.87922353910847, 8.99592866402467, 
                                                                                                             10.1502652300912), fu_time = c(2.19, 4.005, 0, 0.857, 0.745, 
                                                                                                                                            4.153, 1.522, 0, 0.12, 3.184, 0, 0.802, 0.517, 1.859, 0.268, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0.799, 0.446, 0.78, 0, 0, 2.185, 0.953, 1.457, 3.888, 
                                                                                                                                            0.268, 1.295, 0, 3.967, 4.375, 0, 0, 0.479, 0.159, 1.29, 
                                                                                                                                            0, 0, 0.734, 0, 0, 0, 3.584, 0, 0.997, 1.106, 1.506, 0, 0.307, 
                                                                                                                                            0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"))
```

The regression is specified as follows:

```
regression <- 
  lme(fixed=continuous_outcome_log ~ 1 + fu_time + age*fu_time,
      random=~1|pat_id, 
      data=mydata, 
      correlation=corCAR1(form=~1 + fu_time|pat_id),
      na.action="na.omit",
      method="REML", 
      control=lmeControl(opt="optim"))
```

I've subsequently plotted the predicted values of the model as follows:

```
# Make a prediction dataframe
pframe <- 
  expand.grid(
    fu_time=mean(mydata$fu_time),
age=seq(min(mydata$age), max(mydata$age), length.out=75))

# Add predictions to this dataframe
pframe$predicted_continuous_outcome <- 
  predict(regression, newdata=pframe, level=0)

# Transform (exponentiate) predictions back from the log scale.
pframe$predicted_continuous_outcome <- 
  exp(pframe$predicted_continuous_outcome)

# Make a plot.
predict_plot <- 
  mydata %>% 
  ggplot(
    data=., 
    aes(x=age, y=continuous_outcome)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(
    data=pframe, 
    aes(x=age, y=predicted_continuous_outcome))
predict_plot
```

[image]

My question is: why is the line of predicted values not a straight line? I have not specified any higher order terms in the model, so shouldn't predictions therefore be on a straight line?

Comment: You didn't show us your `regression` model.

Comment: I did! But Ill edit the question so its more visible.

Answer (score 1):

You exponentiated your predictions,

```
pframe$predicted_continuous_outcome <- 
  exp(pframe$predicted_continuous_outcome)
```

Thus, they will show exponential growth.

Incidentally, note that your backtransformation will yield conditional *medians*, not a prediction of the conditional *expectation* as you might expect. [Take a look here](https://otexts.com/fpp3/ftransformations.html) - although this is written in the context of time series forecasting, the bias adjustments will also work in other contexts.

Comment: Hi @Stephan Kolassa, thanks for your answer. 
Would you know if there is a way to 'get back' to the original scale of my predictions (i.e. backtransforming from e-log scale), without inducing exponential growth in the predictions?
Also, after reading the page you referenced and the `fable` vignette, it's not quite clear to me how to perform the bias adjustment. Do I add the overall variance as a constant to the predictions?

Comment: (1) The exponential growth is a direct consequence of the log transformation, and there is no way to back-transform without automatically inducing the exponential pattern. If you do not think this makes sense, then don't log transform. (Log transformations make sense if you suspect an underlying *multiplicative* relationship. A skew in the outcome, by itself, is not a strong reason to log transform.)

Comment: (2) The bias-adjusted backtransformation for a prediction $\hat{y}_i$ would be $\exp(\hat{y}_i)(1+\frac{\hat{\sigma}_i^2}{2})$ with the predicted variance $\hat{\sigma}_i^2$ for that instance. The most common way to estimate this is to assume (a) homoskedasticity, so $\hat{\sigma}^2=\hat{\sigma}_i^2$ does not depend on $i$, and (b) estimating $\hat{\sigma}^2$ by the in-sample residual variance, so overall $\exp(\hat{y}_i)(1+\frac{\sigma^2}{2})$.

Comment: Thats a pity. I transformed my outcome because the original model I specified,using the untransformed outcome violated the assumption (very much) of normally distributed residuals. Log transforming my outcome resulted in more normally distributed residuals, which is why I did that.